# Swing Animations: is there a GUI library animation like jquery (javascript) but for java?

Tags: user-interface, swing, animation

Is there a library available to animate and make java GUI look nice, with animations and transitions like jquery does?

something like css hover, make a panel animate,  round the corners of panels so that they look more sophisticated... etc. etc.

So far my exploration has taken me to try java css by Ethan Nicholson, which appears to have been discontinued from the java.net site? and does not appear to have been loaded anywhere else.

And then there is the Chet Haase work  on the timing framework for animating swing, and other nice stuff using the SwingX framework.

Anyone got any advice on an open source animation library specifically designed for swing components? Or am I dreaming and should I be hauling out the wallet to pay for someone else's hard labour?

Answer (score 5):

Kirill Grouchnikov created an excellent **animation library called Trident**. More information can be found at http://kenai.com/projects/trident/pages/Home